# Checking if element loaded, document.getElementById is not working although Id exists

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

`document.getElementById is not working.`, but i can see that `id="calendar1_dayId2017-07-17"`  exists in the DOM, namely in table :

`<td class="dayNumber" id="calendar1_dayId2017-07-17"> <span class="otherDate">17</span> <span class="date" hidden="">2017-07-17</span></td>`

```
$( document ).ready( function() {  
  <...>
  var day_Id = "calendar1_dayId2017-07-17"; 
  someFnc.prototype.getId = function(day_Id) {  
        <...>
        var tempInstFnc = function () { 
            console.log('in tempInstFnc'); 
        } 

      var loadTemp = new loadElemProt( day_Id, tempInstFnc );
      loadTemp.checkLoadInt = window.setInterval( function() { 
            loadTemp.checkLoadFnc(); }, 1000 ); 

      var temp = document.getElementById( "calendar1_dayId2017-07-17" )
      console.log('temp=');   console.log(temp); // null
  } //someFnc.prototype.getId = function(day_Id) { 

 }); //$( document ).ready(function() {
```

Below are helping functions which i load before the code above
They never finish,   `console.log('startedFnc loadElemProt.checkLoadFnc'); //logs forever`

```
var loadElemProt = function ( elemId, userFnc ) {
    console.log('STARTED loadElemProt constructor  elemId='+elemId )
    this.elemId = elemId; 
    this.userFnc = userFnc;
}; //  var loadElemProt = function () {

loadElemProt.prototype.checkLoadFnc = function() {
    console.log('startedFnc loadElemProt.checkLoadFnc'); //logs forever
    if(document.getElementById(this.elemId)) { this.stopIntervalFnc(); }
}; //loadElemProt.prototype.checkLoadFnc = function() {

loadElemProt.prototype.stopIntervalFnc = function() {
    console.log('startedFnc loadElemProt.stopIntervalFnc');
    clearInterval(this.checkLoadInt);
    this.callUserFnc();
}   // loadElemProt.prototype.stopIntervalFnc = function() {

loadElemProt.prototype.callUserFnc = function() {
    this.userFnc.call( null )
}
```

Comment: The reason was that in some other part of code i created an duplicate element having the same id, thus it was two elements with the same id , and this have caused this weird error.

Comment: If you have solved the issue and the answer isn't helpful, please delete your question.